# How to use Monadic binding operator on ADT or record syntax

Tags: haskell, monads

Hello can someone please explain me how can you use the monadic binding operator  on a field of an Algebraic Data Type or record syntax?

#### E.g.

```
data M = M {myfield :: Int}
data N = N Int
```

So for `M` if i want to extract the value from an `IO Int` action into `myfield`  it seems i can't say:

```
a = M { return 3 >>= value }
```

Also how can I bind for an `N` type?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The field has type `Int`, so you can't bind it to anything of a different type, like `IO Int`.

You can however, run the `IO Int` action, get an `Int` back, and use that.

```
foo :: IO Something
foo = do
  i <- return 3  -- run your (IO Int) action
  let a = M { myfield = i }
  ...
  -- at the end, you have to use an (IO Something) action
```

Instead you can convert `N` to `M` as follows

```
convertNtoM :: N -> M
convertNtoM (N i) = M { myfield = i }
```

This, again, does not bind a `N` value to `myfield`, but binds the integer "inside" the `N` value.

---

In the case one has several actions to run, and many fields to fill, one can use the "applicative style".

```
data K = K Int Int Int Int

action :: IO Int
action = return 3

foo :: IO K
foo = K <$> action <*> action <*> action <*> action
```

Comment: I understand that you can obtain what i want inside a `do` block but, i thought that  if you have a `type` with many fields that need extracting from `actions`  there has to be a quick way to write :  `data K=K Int Int Int` something like `a=K (action0>>=) (action1>>=) ...etc`. I thought  that everything that you can accomplish using `do` you can without it too.

Comment: Do you need any import for using the applicative because i get error when trying to use it like this in ghci: `data M=M Int Int ;  f = return 3; a= M <$> f  <*> f`

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian you shouldn't. (<*>) and (<$>) are exported by Prelude on modern GHC versions. which GHC version do you use? You should also make this a separate question.

Comment: I am using `version 8.0.2`

Comment: So it should work. You should make it a separate question and don't forget to include the error message.